# Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) error ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I try to run the  tutorial that  demonstrates training a simple Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) to classify CIFAR images.The tutorial is on the following Tehsorflow website https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn?authuser=1#verify_the_data
When i try to Download and prepare the CIFAR10 dataset i receive the following Traceback:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yT2c.jpg

Can anyone knows what exactly means this traceback??
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is due to website down on which the dataset is exist.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the text without posting an image?